# Remove or update objects in array while iterating in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for an efficient way to iterate over an array of objects and according to some conditions either update an attribute or remove the object or leave it as is.
For example, let's say I have an array of Persons and each person has a name and age, and I want to iterate over the array and remove persons over the age of 40, append "_child" to the name of persons younger than 10 and leave the rest.
I can do:

```
persons.delete_if{|p| p.age > 40}
persons.each{|p| p.name = "#{p.name}_child" if p.age < 10}
```

but is there a clever way to combine them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, actually. (ruby 2.7+)

```rb
persons = persons.filter_map do |p|
  if p.age <= 40
    p.name += "_child" if p.age < 10
    p
  end
end
```

But I personally would keep them separate

```rb
persons = persons
            .reject{|p| p.age > 40}
            .each{|p| p.name += "_child" if p.age < 10 }
```

Comment: Further to your recommendation: Even that code looks *odd* to me, because it's doing multiple things in one place! (A key principle of good code is that each method/function should *only do one thing*.) Removing 'old' people from the list and changing the name of 'young' people in the list feels like two completely different actions to me, and I'd be quite likely to avoid chaining those method calls together directly.

Comment: @TomLord: that's a great point!

Comment: I just wanted to avoid iterating twice on the same array. This is just an example, in my code there is a relation between the 2 actions, both are kind of deleting the object, either remove it completely or mark it as deleted.